# SQL Server convert string to datetime error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert the following string into a datetime type in SQL server. The following is the command I used, and I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '05/06/2006 11:47:40:788545 AM', 131);
```

Comment: You can use `CAST('05/06/2006 11:47:40' as DATETIME)`

Comment: Is there really a : between seconds and milliseconds ?

Comment: The documentation suggests that the format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM` but every example I see of `131` format is a decimal second with three sigfigs.

Comment: @JNevill the format you show works fine, but as you have noted, its only 3 millisecond digits, and no space between the ms and the AM - so its not the same format as used by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a : between seconds and milliseconds, you can use datetime2

**Example**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), stuff('05/06/2006 11:47:40:788545 AM',20,1,'.'))
```

**Results**

```
2006-05-06 11:47:40.7885450
```

If you use `datetime2(3)`, you can knock it down to 3 decimals (rounded) `2006-05-06 11:47:40.789`